# Complex parameterization In Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, loadrunner

There is data dependancy i.e., COMPANYID 1 , SOURCEID 1, CS1 file so User1 should pick COMPANYID 1 , SOURCEID 1, CSV1 file

User2 should pick COMPANYID 2 , SOURCEID 2, CSV2 file

User3 should pick COMPANYID 3 , SOURCEID 3, CSV3 file

Could anyone please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions combination.

1. `__threadNum()` returns the current virtual user number, User1 will get 1, User2 will get 2, etc.
2. `__CSVRead()` takes file path as an argument so if you do something like:

   ```
   ${__CSVRead(test${__threadNum}.csv,0)}
   ```

   - User1 will read the line from test1.csv file
   - User2 will read the line from test2.csv file
   - etc.

[image]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.